# Extract the record for last hour for specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I am trying to extract the last hour (TKT_DT) record for number of tickets (TKT_DN) from sales table (PS_TKT_HIST) for specific date (BUS_DAT).

I have the following code but it extracts the number of tickets (TKT_NO) for each hour. I want to filter the last hour only. Here is the code I used:

```
Select count(TKT_NO) AS SAL_TKTS, 
  DATEPART(HOUR, (TKT_DT))AS SAL_HR
FROM PS_TKT_HIST
WHERE BUS_DAT = '2022-03-30'
GROUP By DATEPART (HOUR, TKT_DT)
```

I get the flowing results

```
SAL_TKTS    SAL_HR
5             10
1             11
3             12
5             13
10            14
13            15
23            16
18            17
12            18
6             19
6             20
4             21
```

I want to get only the record (4) for the last hour (21)

Comment: Your question is not clear - which is why it is highly recommended to provide a script containing DDL and sample data along with the desired results matching that data. Perhaps you just need to add a filter to your WHERE clause to include those rows that have the same hour as that of the maximum value from the associated column for the specified date (hint). Alternatively, you could simply select the "top 1" row (descending - another hint).

Comment: Please take a moment to review the [help section on editing](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the number of tickets in the last hour on a given day:

```
DECLARE @date date = '20220330';

SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.PS_TKT_HIST
  WHERE BUS_DAT = @date
  AND TKT_DAT >= DATEADD(HOUR, 23, CONVERT(datetime2, @date));
```

For any hour other than the last hour (let's say, the 9PM hour):

```
WHERE BUS_DAT = @date
  AND TKT_DAT >= DATEADD(HOUR, 21, CONVERT(datetime2, @date))
  AND TKT_DAT <  DATEADD(HOUR, 22, CONVERT(datetime2, @date));
```

If by "last hour" you don't mean 11 PM but rather *the last hour there was a sale*, you would have to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @date date = '20220330';

SELECT TOP (1) COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.PS_TKT_HIST
  WHERE BUS_DAT = @date
  GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, TKT_DAT)
  ORDER BY DATEPART(HOUR, TKT_DAT) DESC;
```

Comment: Could you do not declare the date as certain date as I used that date as example. I wish if I can be able to get the last hour record for day I choose

Comment: @BahaaGerges Yes presumably you would populate that yourself or use a stored procedure and it would be an input parameter. You have to declare it _somewhere_, right? The queries themselves will work with whatever date you declare exactly once. And typically (especially in this case) you don't want to hard-code the date _into the query_, you want it to be defined once, up front.

Comment: The last one is exactly the one I want, thank you so much

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but Could you edit this code to extract the last hour for every day of last week? I want to see last hour for each day in last week (Mon to Sunday)