# SQL SELECT COUNT with Multiple WHERE conditions and based on MAX value of one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count number of columns contain specific text based on multiple WHERE LIKE condition for MAX value only.

| ID | Name | Text | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Al | New | 1 |
| 2 | Al | NA | 2 |
| 3 | Al | NA | 3 |
| 4 | Al | NA | 3 |
| 5 | BK | New | 1 |
| 9 | BK | Old | 2 |
| 7 | BK | NA | 3 |

I want to COUNT following (All rows WHERE Names is Like Al and Text is New only or rows which has the max value in this example value of 3):
The results for the above table should be 2 as there are two lines which meets the criteria.

| ID | Name | Text | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Al | NA | 3 |
| 4 | Al | NA | 3 |

```
SELECT COUNT(Text) AS NA WHERE Name LIKE 'AL' AND Text LIKE 'NA' AND Max(Value)
```

I know the above query is totally wrong but I am trying to explain what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here, I'm afraid. You talk about `COUNT`ing, but what is it you're `COUNT`ing here exactly? The `COUNT` of a single **row** (not `line`) is `1` or `0` (if the value being counted is `NULL`). You need to elaborate further here and provide expected results. Also why is `'AI'` in the data you want to "count", but `'BK'` isn't?

Comment: What is  `COUNT(Text) AS NA` mean for your expected result?

Comment: It looks like you want to select specific rows from the table only where the `VALUE` column  contains the MAX value - yes?

Comment: I updated the question with more text.
With COUNT(Text) AS NA I want to count rows which has Text NA in Text filed.

Comment: @Geezer Exactly Rows where Name is Like AL and Text is Like NA WHERe column Value contains MAX value.

Comment: Why `LIKE`? `LIKE` is for pattern matching. You merely want `=`: `WHERE Name = 'AL' AND Text = 'NA'`.

Comment: Sounds a lot like [this question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71728759/extract-the-record-for-last-hour-for-specific-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subquery for the max value:

```
select count(*)
from mytable
where name = 'Al' and text = 'NA' and value = (select max(value) from mytable);
```

Comment: I just found that if there is only one record (1) in value column this returns no records.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that the query doesn't work when all rows have the value 1? I don't see how this could be a problem. The query looks for the maximum value in the table. Then it looks at all the rows with that maximum value. Those that are 'Al'/'NA' get counted. This is how I understand the task. If this is not what you want, then my query doesn't work for you, of course.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for and works fine as long as I have multiple Entries which matches 'AL/NA' if I have only 1 entry 'AL/NA/1' then it does not return any results.

Comment: If you have one entry 'AL/NA/1' and 1 is the greatest value in the whole table, then you should get this row. If the greatest value is higher, say 3 as in your example, then you don't get the row, because we are supposed to only look at rows with the greatest value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a CTE with `DENSE_RANK` and then a `COUNT`?

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           Name,
           Text,
           Value,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Value] DESC) AS DR
    FROM(VALUES(1,'Al','New',1),
               (2,'Al','NA',2),
               (3,'Al','NA',3),
               (4,'Al','NA',3),
               (5,'BK','New',1),
               (9,'BK','Old',2),
               (7,'BK','NA',3))V(ID,Name,Text,Value)
    WHERE Name = 'Al'
      AND Text = 'NA')
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CTE
WHERE DR = 1;
```